# Incorrect Syntax Left Join subquery with aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, subquery

I'm trying to run the following query through SQL Server.  I keep getting a incorrect syntax error near',' but I can't figure out which comma is incorrect.  I'm pretty new to SQL but especially still trying to figure out more complex queries.

```
SELECT
   lastdate.[Date of Record],
   billing.[Club Code],
   billing.[Club Name],
   lastdate.[Member Code with Name],
   billing.[Activity Code],
   billing.[Category Code],
   billing.[Dues Net Amount],
   billing.[Dues Gross Amount],
   billing.[Member Type Code],
   billing.[Member Join Date],
   billing.[Member Status Rule Code]
FROM
    [dbo].[view_Club_Transactions_0100_(15) Dues_Summary] billing
LEFT JOIN
        (MAX(lastdate.[Date of Record]) dor,
        lastdate.[Member Code with Name]
    FROM
        [dbo].[view_Club_Transactions_0100_(15) Dues_Summary] lastdate
    GROUP BY
        lastdate.[Member Code with Name])
ON
    billing.[Member Code with Name]=lastdate.[Member Code with Name]
WHERE
   ([Member Status Rule Code] = N'ZRESIGN')
   AND
   ([Activity Code] = N'DUES')
```

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subquery is missing the `SELECT` keyword... And an alias too. You also need to align the subquery column alias for the date column with the outer query:

```
SELECT
    lastdate.[Max Date of Record],      ---------------> column alias
    billing.[Club Code],
    ...
FROM [dbo].[view_Club_Transactions_0100_(15) Dues_Summary] billing
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT              -------------------------------> "SELECT" keyword
        MAX([Date of Record]) [Max Date of Record], ---> column alias
        [Member Code with Name]
    FROM [dbo].[view_Club_Transactions_0100_(15) Dues_Summary]
    GROUP BY [Member Code with Name]
) lastdate              -------------------------------> subquery alias
ON billing.[Member Code with Name]=lastdate.[Member Code with Name]
WHERE ...
```

I actually suspect that you can skip the self join and use window functions instead. That could be:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
       MAX([Date of Record]) OVER(PARTITION BY [Member Code with Name]) [Max Date of Record],
       [Club Code],
       [Club Name],
       [Member Code with Name],
       [Activity Code],
       [Category Code],
       [Dues Net Amount],
       [Dues Gross Amount],
       [Member Type Code],
       [Member Join Date],
       [Member Status Rule Code]
    FROM [dbo].[view_Club_Transactions_0100_(15) Dues_Summary] 
) t
WHERE [Member Status Rule Code] = N'ZRESIGN' AND [Activity Code] = N'DUES'
```